# Export ReduceRegion fixedHistogram toDrive

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, histogram, reducers

I'm trying to export a fixed histogram from reduceRegion as a .csv file. I'm sure im missing the obvious here, but can't find a reasonable example that does this straightforward. I can do it as a FeatureCollection, but the format is difficult. I was thinking 2 columns for values and counts, like when you export your histograms as from the console.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/296846e47fe937897dda456d4552a39b

```
var landsat = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA").filterBounds(geometry).first())

var index = 'B1'

function country (image) {var c = image.reduceRegion({
  geometry: image.geometry(),
  reducer: ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram(0, 1, 1000),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e12,
}); return ee.Feature(null, c.select(['B1']))}



var hist = landsat.select(index).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram(0, 1, 1000), 
  geometry: landsat.geometry(), 
  scale:100, //.add(upScale),
  bestEffort: true,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
print(hist)

var featureTest = ee.Feature(null, hist);
print(featureTest)

// Gives a difficult format
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection([featureTest]),
  description: 'exportTableExample',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});

var list = ee.Array(hist.values().get(0))
print(list, 'list')

var means = list.slice(1, 0, 1).multiply(1000).round().divide(1000).project([0]).toList()
var counts = list.slice(1, 1, 2).project([0]).toList(); 
print(means, counts)

var fromList = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(means, counts)
print(fromList)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make one feature for every mean/count combination:

```
// Make a feature collection
var indices = ee.List.sequence(0,means.length().subtract(1))
var feats = ee.FeatureCollection(indices.map(function(index){
  return ee.Feature(null, {mean: means.get(index), 
                           count: counts.get(index),
  });
}));

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: feats,
  description: 'exportTableExample',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
  selectors: ['mean', 'count']
});
```

[link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f920ce4825160503991a2d1ae7ffe29c)